# How to get a value from another controller class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have two controller classes `AuthenticationController` and `RegisterUrlController`.

I would want to call a function in `AuthenticationController` class called `authorization` to return a value and use the value in the `RegisterUrlController` class and function `registerUrl` as the `ACCESS_TOKEN` variable on the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER array value.

See sample code;

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\C2B;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class RegisterUrlController extends Controller
{

    public function registerUrl(Request $request)
    {

        $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        // The ACCESS_TOKEN should be passed from the other class 
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
        array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN')
             ); 

            $curl_post_data = array(
              //Fill in the request parameters with valid values
              'ShortCode' => $request->ShortCode,
              'ResponseType' => 'ResponseType',
              'ConfirmationURL' => $request->confirmation_url,
              'ValidationURL' => $request->validation_url
            );

            $data_string = json_encode($curl_post_data);

            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

            $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
            print_r($curl_response);

            echo $curl_response;


            curl_close($curl);

    }
}
```

The class generating the `ACCESS_TOKEN` above is below.

How do I pass this return value to be the `ACCESS_TOKEN` value on the array header above?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthenticationController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }


    public function authorization()
    {

            $curl = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

            $credentials = base64_encode('statum:ub435!');
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Basic '.$credentials)); //setting a custom header
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

            $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

            return json_decode($curl_response); //this is the response I need passed over to the other class


   }
}
```

Question, how do I go about getting values from another controller?

Anyone?

Comment: The short answer, make `authorization` method to a `trait` method and use it in every controller that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use few ways to do this

1. Extends Class
2. Create Class Object
3. Use Namespace
4. Make Authentication Service and then call it